# Why does Python's cProfile report a different elapsed time than using time.time() deltas when using PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

I am profiling some code using PyTorch. I am aware the CUDA normally has some asynchronous execution (see [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.0/notes/cuda.html#asynchronous-execution)), but I believe that transferring from GPU to CPU will generally force synchronization.

For this reason, I decided to naively profile using `cProfile`, but I notice that the time reported by `Profile.enable() ... Profile.disable()` was different than the time recorded across `time.time()` (as a delta).

Here's what the code looks like at a high-level:

```py
gpu = torch.device("cuda")
cpu = torch.device("cpu")

setup = Setup()
net = make_fcn_resnet50(num_classes=setup.D)
net.eval().to(gpu)

rgb_tensor = setup.sample(device=cpu)

pr = profile.Profile()
pr.enable()
t_start = time.time()

rgb_tensor = rgb_tensor.to(gpu)
y = net(rgb_tensor)
dd_tensor = y["out"]
dd_mean = torch.mean(dd_tensor[[0]]).to(cpu).numpy()
assert dd_mean is not None

dt = time.time() - t_start
pr.disable()
stats = pstats.Stats(pr)

stats.print_stats(5)
print(f"dt: {dt:.4f}s")
```

Here's the discrepancy I see:

```
2925 function calls (2734 primitive calls) in 0.009 seconds
...
dt: 0.0355s
```

I would've expected cProfile to report about 35ms (same as `dt`), but instead it reports about 10ms.

Why does this happen?

Full code + repro is here: 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/bdef8a14/python/cprofile_with_torch

Comment: In general, you might want to include `torch.cuda.synchronize()` above each call to `time.time()`. Greetings from Helsinki! -Yaniel

Answer (score 1):

Empirically, it seems like `cProfile` will not "hook" into the code if you don't "flush" all of the outputs, or if you're code isn't fully wrapped in a function.

See more detail in the comments here: 
https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/bdef8a14b5/python/cprofile_with_torch/repro.py#L75-L94

All timing results recorded with:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- CPython 3.6.9
- nvidia-driver-450 (450.102.04-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
- NVidia Titan RTX

---

That all being said, may be better just to use PyTorch's provided mechanisms (:facepalm:):

- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/profiler.html
- https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html